# In Rust, how does one sum the distinct first components of `Some` ordered pairs?

Tags: rust, sum, tuples

In the Rust program below, `pair` is a vector of `Option` values, where each `Option` value is `Some` ordered pair.  My ***goal*** is to: (1) extract the first components of these ordered pairs, then (2) sum the ***distinct*** values that result from step (1).  My attempt at this is shown below:

```
fn main() {
    let pair: Vec<Option<(u32, Vec<u32>)>> = vec![
        Some((2, vec![1, 0])),
        Some((7, vec![0, 1])),
        Some((7, vec![])),
        Some((3, vec![1, 1])),
        Some((2, vec![0, 1, 0])),
    ];

    let mut values = pair.iter().map(|opt| opt.unwrap().0).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    values.sort();
    values.dedup();
    let distinct_sum: u32 = values.iter().sum();

    println!("The sum of the distinct values should be 2+7+3=12.");
    println!("The sum actually is {}", distinct_sum);
} // end main
```

But the Rust compiler tells me (regarding `opt`) that I `cannot move out of borrowed content`.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> src/main.rs:10:44
   |
10 |     let mut values = pair.iter().map(|opt| opt.unwrap().0).collect::<Vec<_>>();
   |                                            ^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction in order to achieve the above goal?

Comment: `let mut values = pair.iter().filter_map(|opt| opt.as_ref().map(|x| x.0)).collect::<Vec<_>>();`

Comment: You can use `into_iter()` instead of `iter()` if consuming the input is OK. Else use the solution from the linked question: `opt.as_ref().unwrap()`.